# nodejs native module can't complie in window xp (nodejs v0.8)

Tags: windows, node.js, module

I write a shapelib binding for nodejs, it can be compiled in linux, but when I compiled it it windows XP with VS2005, I got an error:

`deps\uv\include\uv-private/uv-win.h(181) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'srwlock_'`

after googling, I find that SRW Locks are not available under Windows XP,that's why I got the error.

My question is why nodejs can be used in Windows XP? It is not use the SRW Lock?

Comment: Try to update to VS2010.

Comment: I commented out that line of code and it seemed to avoid that error, but of course now I've got other errors. They seem to be unrelated though